# Java: Do While with || and && operators

Tags: java, logical-operators

so I'm a bit confused on the following:

While testing the Boolean, my first impression was to use the || operator for the conditions. This did not work, the loop would keep repeating for a correct response. But if I used the && operator, then it would evaluate the conditions the way I wanted it to.

I feel like this is backwards, and I'm not looking at it right. Can anyone explain this?

To make it more clear, what I was originally trying to do:

```
    String input;
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

do
{
    System.out.print("Enter one of the following names: John, Katie, Richard");
    input = keyboard.nextLine();
    input = input.toLowerCase();

} while ( !input.equalsIgnoreCase("John") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("Katie") && !input.equalsIgnoreCase("Richard"));
```

I want the loop to repeat until one of the given names is entered. So if I entered katie, it should move on, but if I enter bob it should repeat.

So if I enter john, the boolean first checks that. !(john = john) which is  FT = false.
since I just want to check to see if it is equal to john, not richard or katie I would want to use the || operator. Why would I also want to check if its equal to those names anyway.

Comment: Do you know what `&&` does? Do you know what `||` does? What's confusing to you?

Comment: Where is `mediumInput` getting set?  The `keyboard.nextLine()` is being placed into `input`.

Comment: [De Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) may be helpful here

Comment: Tip: use `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of `compareToIgnoreCase() ==0` - it might be more clear that way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basic boolean logic. Your statement is equivalent to `!A && !B && !C` - that in turn is equivalent to `!(A || B || C)`

The simplest way to reason about these is via logic tables:

```
A B C | !A !B !C | !A && !B && !C | A || B || C | !(A || B || C)
------+----------+----------------+-------------+---------------
F F F |  T  T  T |        T       |      F      |        T      
T F F |  F  T  T |        F       |      T      |        F      
F T F |  T  F  T |        F       |      T      |        F      
T T F |  F  F  T |        F       |      T      |        F      
F F T |  T  T  F |        F       |      T      |        F      
T F T |  F  T  F |        F       |      T      |        F      
F T T |  T  F  F |        F       |      T      |        F      
T T T |  F  F  F |        F       |      T      |        F
```

As you can see the two expressions have the same boolean values in all cases.

Answer (score 0):

```
while ( !(mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("one") ==0
    && !(mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("two") == 0)
    && !(mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("three") == 0));
```

Too many double negatives here. You're just confusing yourself. Look at it this way:

```
while (mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("one") != 0
    && mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("two") != 0
    && mediumInput.compareToIgnoreCase("three") != 0);
```

You can see immediately that using `||` wouldn't make sense. You don't want to loop while when any of these is false: only while all of them are.